# "Immutable" Byte Array or Object Locks?

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, immutability

I'm developing a multithreaded modbus server, and I will need to manage a block of bytes for the client(s) to read.  Each modbus device will have a thread to update their respective portion of the byte array, so I will need to implement some form of locking.

When the application is initialized, the number of devices and the number of bytes of memory allocated to each device will be constant.  I did some research, and it seems that it's safe to lock a multidimensional array with an array of `ReaderWriterLockSlim` Objects to be used as locks:

```
    private static ReaderWriterLockSlim[] memLock;
    private static byte[][] memoryBlock;
    ...
    //Modify or read memoryBlock corresponding to deviceIndex as needed using:
    memLock[deviceIndex].EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            // Write to array of bytes from memoryBlock
            memoryBlock[2][3] = 0x05;
        }
        finally
        {
            memLock[deviceIndex].ExitWriteLock();
        }

        memLock[deviceIndex].EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            // Read array of bytes from memoryBlock
        }
        finally
        {
            memLock[deviceIndex].ExitReadLock();
        }
```

I have not written a lot of multithreaded applications, and I only recently "discovered" the concept of immutability.  Here is my stab at turning the above into an immutable class, assuming a set list of devices and a memory size that never changes after the memory is `Initialize`ed.  The reason the class is `static` is because there will only be 1 instance of this class in my application:

```
    private static class DeviceMemory
    {
        private static bool initialized_ = false;
        private static int memSizeInBytes_;
        private static List<byte[]> registers_;
        public static void Initialize(int deviceCount, int memSizeInBytes)
        {
            if (initialized_) throw new Exception("DeviceMemory already initialized");
            if (memSizeInBytes <= 0) throw new Exception("Invalid memory size in bytes");
            memSizeInBytes_ = memSizeInBytes;
            registers_ = new List<byte[]>();
            for(int i=0; i<deviceCount;++i)
            {
                byte[] scannerRegs = new byte[memSizeInBytes];
                registers_.Add(scannerRegs);
            }
            initialized_ = true;
        }
        public static byte[] GetBytes(int deviceIndex)
        {
            if (initialized_) return registers_[deviceIndex];
            else return null;
        }
        public static void UpdateBytes(int deviceIndex, byte[] memRegisters)
        {
            if (!initialized_) throw new Exception("Memory has not been initialized");
            if (memRegisters.Length != memSizeInBytes_)
                throw new Exception("Memory register size does not match the defined memory size in bytes: " + memSizeInBytes_);
            registers_[deviceIndex] = memRegisters;
        }
    }
```

Here are my questions about the above:

1. Am I correct that I can lock a row of the 2 dimensional array as shown above?
2. Have I properly implemented an immutable class? i.e. Do you see any issues with the `DeviceMemory` class that would prevent me from writing to the `UpdateBytes` method from the device thread and read simultaneously from multiple clients on different thread?
3. Is this immutable class a wise choice over the more traditional multi-dimensional byte array/lock?  Specifically, I'm concerned about memory usage/garbage collection since updates to the byte arrays will actually be "new" byte arrays that replace the reference to the old array.  The reference to the old array should be released immediately after the client reads it, however.  There will be about 35 devices updating every second and 4 clients per device reading at approximately 1 second intervals.
4. Would once solution or the other perform better, especially if the server were to scale out?

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what you've shown in your second code example is not an "immutable class", but rather a "static class". Two very different things; you'll want to review your terminology to ensure that you are communicating effectively, as well as not becoming confused when researching techniques related to either.

As for your questions:

> 1.Am I correct that I can lock a row of the 2 dimensional array as shown above?

You should use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` instead, and you didn't show any mechanism for catching the timeout exception should one occur. But otherwise, yes…you can use an individual lock for each `byte[]` element of the `byte[][]` object.

More generally, you can use a lock to represent whatever unit of data or other resource you want. The lock object doesn't care.

> 2.Have I properly implemented an immutable class? i.e. Do you see any issues with the DeviceMemory class that would prevent me from writing to the UpdateBytes method from the device thread and read simultaneously from multiple clients on different thread?

If you really mean "immutable", then no. If you really mean "static", then yes, but it's not clear to me that knowing that is useful. The class isn't thread-safe, which seems to be your greater concern, so in that respect you haven't done it right.

As far as the `UpdateBytes()` method itself goes, there's nothing wrong with it per se. And indeed, since copying a reference from one variable to another is an atomic operation in .NET, the `UpdateBytes()` method can "safely" update the array element at the same time some other thread is trying to retrieve it. "Safely" in the sense that a reader won't get corrupted data.

But there's nothing in your class that ensures that `Initialize()` is called only once. In addition, without synchronization (a lock or marking variables `volatile`) you have no guarantees that values written in one thread will ever be observed by another thread. That includes all of the fields, as well as the individual `byte[]` array elements.

> 3.Is this immutable class a wise choice over the more traditional multi-dimensional byte array/lock? Specifically, I'm concerned about memory usage/garbage collection since updates to the byte arrays will actually be "new" byte arrays that replace the reference to the old array. The reference to the old array should be released immediately after the client reads it, however. There will be about 35 devices updating every second and 4 clients per device reading at approximately 1 second intervals.

There's not enough context in your question to make a comparison, as we have no idea how you'd otherwise access the `memoryBlock` array. If you're just copying new arrays into the array, the two should be similar. Even if it's only in the second example that you are creating new arrays, then assuming the arrays are not large, I would expect the generation of ~100 new objects per second to be well within the bandwidth of the garbage collector.

As far as whether the approach in your second code example is a desirable approach, I will with all due respect suggest that you should probably stick to a conventionally synchronized code (i.e. with `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, or even just a plain `lock` statement). Concurrency is hard enough to get right with regular locks, never mind trying to write lock-free code. Given the update rates you're describing, I would expect a plain `lock` statement would work just fine.

If you run into some bandwidth problems, then at least you have a known-good implementation with which to compare new implementations, and will have a better idea of just how complicated an implementation you really require.

4.Would once solution or the other perform better, especially if the server were to scale out?

Impossible to say without more details.

Comment: Thanks, @Peter. I'll use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` instead if I go the locking route.

Comment: Thanks, @Peter, hit Enter prematurely! It sounds like `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is the most direct route for a threading rookie such as myself.  It is indeed the thread safety that I'm concerned about, not necessarily the adherence to the principles of immutability, but I think I understand what you mean when you say that `Initialize()` can be called repeatedly, thus changing the whole list of bytes and thwarting the immutability of the class.  For my own sake, I will do some more research on the `volatile` keyword and value synchronizations between threads!

Comment: I updated the original question to reflect your suggestions.  Is my class immutable now, or did I miss something?  More importantly, would it make this thread safe for reading/writing if I were to wrap the `return registers_[deviceIndex];` and `registers_[deviceIndex] = memRegisters;` lines in `Thread.MemoryBarrier()`.  Is it really that simple?

Comment: Using a memory barrier before reads and after writes can address data visibility issues. It doesn't guarantee thread-safety, but if you are careful about how you use the methods in which the barriers are used, the code _can_ be used in a thread-safe way. As far as "immutable" goes, it's not clear to me you understand the term. "Immutable" means that the data in the class doesn't change; given your apparent goal here (to provide a mechanism through which data can flow), immutability seems not even to be what you want, and for sure is not what you've achieved.

Comment: Note that it is generally frowned upon for a question to be revised significantly from its original form, as doing so invalidates commentary and answers that have been provided so far. If you must provide an update, simply _add_ new discussion to the question. If you want to make large changes to example code, it's better to start with a new question (including a link to the previous one if you feel that will help comprehension of the new one).

Comment: Thanks @Peter.  After a little digging, it looks like List<> isn't thread safe at all, so locking would be required around access to the List itself.  Looking at examples of immutable classes (i.e. Eric Lippert's blog posts, such as [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/04/immutability-in-c-part-two-a-simple-immutable-stack.aspx), I see what you mean -- I'm confusing "immutable" with "thread-safe".  I'll keep in mind your note about editing in the future.  I thought it would keep track of my edit comment to let folks reading it to know my changes!

Comment: `List<T>` is not itself thread-safe, but it is possible to use it in a thread-safe way. Locking is the simplest route to thread safety, but careful use of memory barriers can achieve the same. As far as editing goes, yes...the site tracks your edits. But it's not a good idea to expect readers to sift through the edits to understand the presentation. Edits should be used for fixing posts, not for use as a ongoing discussion.